# Updating Person Accounts when new campaign is created

Tags: apex, process-builder, architecture

I am not sure what the best way to do this is but I am trying to update a field to find out when a person account has entered a campaign for the first time. We are using campaigns that are coming over from Zapier. If the Person Account is created then we wanted the campaign name to be stamped on Campaign Origin. I was thinking about doing this via process builder but I don't seem to be able to. Any thoughts as to what would work the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading what you're looking for correctly, you need to run your process builder on the Campaign Member object. If you do that, on creation, you'll be able to update the related contact or the account related to that contact (depending on where the Campaign origin exists). Here's a general outline of how you would accomplish this in Process Builder:

- Object: Campaign Member

  - Start the Process: only when a record is created
- Define Criteria for this Action Group: "Campaign Origin" **Equals** *Global Constant* **Null**
- Record Type: Select a record related to the Campaign Member

  - if the field is contact, then select **ContactId**, if Account Select **Contact Id >** then click on **Account Id**
  - Select the field you wish to update, then use the **Field Reference** type

    - Select **Campaign Id >** then select the **Name** field.
    - Save

I didn't include the various names of the steps, you'll need to choose what works best for you. But if you follow that general outline you should be good to go.

Comment: Success. Thank you for that help! When I tried it kept failing but wasn't sure what I was doing wrong.